# Linear combination of vectors that minimizes their L1 norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a representation of an orthogonal basis for a subspace of a much larger space. I think that it would be easier to get an idea of what these basis vectors were like if they were sparse (i.e. were mostly zero), like [1,-2,1,0,0,0,0,0] instead of dense like they are presently.

If the basis completely spanned the larger space, then the most sparse representation of that basis would be [1,0,0...], [0,1,0...], [0,0,1...] and so on. However, the subspace has only about half the number of dimensions of the space it resides in.

I would like a set of linear combinations of my set of basis vectors, where the new vectors have the same span but are "sparse." One nice formalization of sparseness is the L1 norm, which can be calculated as,
$$
||x||_1 = \sum_{i=0}^n |x_i|
$$
So, formally, given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with orthogonal columns, I would like to find the matrix $P$ so that the column space of $PA$ is the same as that of $A$, and also so that the sum of the absolute values of the entries in $PA$ is minimized. How might this be done?

Comment: To decrease the $L_1$ norm of your basis you can simply scale the basis vectors down. In particular, the sum of the absolute values of the entries does have a minimum.

Comment: And if the dimension of your subspace isn't too big, you could simply compute the left inverse of the matrix whose columns are your basis vectors. What are the dimensions of these spaces?